# Is fputs more efficient than format("%s",..)?

Tags: c, format, stdio

In C code like

```
printf("%s", message);
```

I wonder whether I should rather use

```
fputs(message, stdout);
```

The former code is clearer but is it slower? or uses more memory? I prefer clearer code but not when it looks like wasting time & memory stupidly.

I would love to know that the compiler detects such situations and that the necessary format parsing and interpreting is not done at runtime. After all, `gcc` complains on `printf("")` so compilers may  "understand" formats and preprocess them.

PS: that the former style is clearer is more obvious when writing `format("name=%s\n",unameData.nodename);` rather than
`fputs(stdout,"name=");fputs(stdout,unameData.nodename);putchar('\n');`. This is after all the purpose of having formats.

Comment: Have you tried a couple of benchmark use-cases to test the execution time of each option? If you have, it may be helpful to publish them here. Otherwise, how do you know for sure that one is slower than the other?

Comment: Benchmark! Do both a million times each and see. Not that it matters anyway, as the functions themselves will not be the ones taking all the time, but the actual output to the terminal.

Comment: Clean code is almost always better than efficient code, so optimize bottlenecks if you need to, but in other cases go for readability.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Do not conflate stdout with a tty!  There is no reason to think this output is going to a terminal.

Comment: And if this is being run in a benchmark a million times, it would be wise to ensure that stdout is *not* a tty.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The output doesn't have to go to a terminal, but it's still the actual writing of the output (no matter its destination) that's most likely going to be the "slow" part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One or the other may be more efficient depending on the implementation.

With proper optimization flag, decent compiler should be able to change less efficient form into another (assuming `printf("%s\n", message)`) without programmer's knowledge.

```
$ cat print.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", "Hello world");
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -S -O2 print.c 
$ cat print.s 
    .file   "print.c"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "Hello world"
    ...   
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    call    puts
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    ...
```

`...` represents code omitted for brevity

Comment: 1.0E99 thanks !! I have never used gcc -S but your example shows how it can be used.

Answer (score 2):

While in theory either could be correct, in practice `printf` functions are almost always have higher cost:

- `printf` functions are variable argument functions, which restricts which calling conventions compiler can use. This results in more program memory use, as cleanup is always on caller code. Code might also be slower as parameters must be passed on stack instead of registers.
- `printf` functions tend to have much higher stack usage, due to complex nature of these functions.

While some compiler might detect `printf` and use `puts` instead where possible, in practice compilers for embedded systems are not always that smart, and in that environment the difference really matters.